# Failed to initiate service connection to simulator xcode 11.4.1 and 11.3 and 11.4-beta

Tags: xcode, macos, ios-simulator, macos-catalina

When I build and run any project on Xcode, I face this error:
[image]

On the other hand, when I using command-line and install and launch the app by commands, I can see logs and everything is ok.

I did see other similar questions and I did try solutions like the clean project, build and reset and restart simulator and reinstall various versions of Xcode, but didn't fix.

My OS:
Mac Os Catalina 10.15.4

Comment: Please file a radar (feedback assistant) with a susdiagnose and `xcrun simctl diagnose` after reproducing the issue.  Do you have any 3rd party kexts installed?

Comment: Yes, I installed some kexts, what kexts are related to Xcode or simulator???

Comment: It isn't that there are kexts related to the simulator or Xcode.  The issue is that some kext authors make certain assumptions which are not valid in all cases and thus break software that they were not considering.  I suggest you reach out to the author(s) of those kexts to report issues and hopefully get updated versions with a fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed some additional kexts from EFI partition, this problem solved!.
Thanks to [Jeremy Huddleston Sequoia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/726106/jeremy-huddleston-sequoia)

Comment: Nice. Which of them you have removed?

Comment: Sorry, I don't remember that but I can share configs with you.

Comment: @MohammadRezaEram What was the path of that kexts? I am not sure where to find the EFI partition.